# How to compare the country string value with dropdown value in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I want to select the country from dropdown and send to backend by forming JSON request.

And I need to display the country name from JSON response by comparing the response string with dropdown value.

In my code to display all country I am using an external JavaScript link.

I tried but I can't compare the string value with dropdown.

I tried ng-option also but it doesn't work for me.

The external js link is: `<script src="http://iamrohit.in/lab/js/location.js"></script>`

```
<select name="country" class="form-control1 drop countries" required  ng-model="model.country" placeholder="select" id="countryId sel1">
```

JSON response =

```
{
  "response": {
    "service": {

    },
    "data": {
      "country": "India"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correct - you have dictionary and you want to show this dictionary as your 'select' control and bind to your scoped (found in this dictionary) object?

If yes - here is solution.
Use 'track by' for correct data binding mapping.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope){
  $scope.code = {key:'B', name: 'BB'};
  
  $scope.items = [
      {key:'A', name: 'AA'},
      {key:'B', name: 'BB'},
      {key:'C', name: 'CC'}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
  <select ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.key" ng-model="code"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I am able to select but i want to display the country name in my response by comparing it with the dropdown and show the country name from list.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean :( could you share some example?

Comment: Ok. In my registration page I have selected the country, state and city. In profile page I will get a response with all registered details of mine. In that response I will get country as {"country": "India"}. I am assigning the country value to my ng-model name "$scope.model.country" but i am not able to view my country name in my profile page. Instead it is showing the default dropdown menu of all countries. When i inspect, i saw as "<option value="? string:India ?"></option>".  My model value is not getting matched with the dropdown value.

Comment: I used as <select name="country" class="drop3 countries ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="model.country" placeholder="select" id="countryId sel1" ng-options="country.name for country in countries track by countryId">          and the value is not set. In console i saw as "**<option value="?">Select Country</option>**"

Answer (score 0):

> Ok. In my registration page I have selected the country, state and city. In profile page I will get a response with all registered details of mine. In that response I will get country as {"country": "India"}. I am assigning the country value to my ng-model name "$scope.model.country" but i am not able to view my country name in my profile page. Instead it is showing the default dropdown menu of all countries. When i inspect, i saw as "". My model value is not getting matched with the dropdown value.

Seems this solution also works. Maybe you are setting your scoped values asynchronously? So you need to use $scope.$apply(function-to-update-data) with checking digest is not in processing this moment.

Does it helps?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope){
  $scope.code = 'Ukraine';
  $scope.items = ['Brasil', 'USA', 'Ukraine'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
  <select ng-options="item for item in items" ng-model="code"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I used as <select name="country" class="drop3 countries ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="model.country" placeholder="select" id="countryId sel1" ng-options="country.name for country in countries track by countryId"> and the value is not set. In console i saw as **"<option value="?">Select Country</option>"**